# Jenkins Artifactory Plug-in

Tags: jenkins

I am new to Artifactory so I apologize if this question has already been answered.  I am using rtPromote to Promote Artifactory from one repo (dev) to another repo (qa).  Both dry run and performing promotion completes successful. However, when I check the repo the file wasn't copied over. See snippet below.

Am I missing something with rtPromote or do I need to use something different than rtPromote with Jenkins Atrifactory Plug-in?  Thank you in advance.

```
Performing dry run promotion (no changes are made during dry run)

{

    "messages" : [ ]

}

Dry run finished successfully.

Performing promotion

{

    "messages" : [ ]

}

Promotion completed successfully!
```

Comment: Hi Mike and welcome to Stack Overflow. Thanks for posting a clear and detailed question.